# Video Tracking Using GA Event Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, vimeo, event-tracking

I'm trying to setup GA Event Tracking on my site for an `IFRAME` Vimeo Video embed. However, I can't figure out where/how the tracking object should be placed in my `IFRAME` code.

**Here's my `IFRAME` embed code:**

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/51447433" width="500" 
  height="281"frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen 
  mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Here's what I **think** the [GA Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) code **should** look like:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Title']);">Play</a>
```

Where does this go in my embed code? Can somebody show me how this should look/work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the player API because you can't inject code inside an iframe on a third party domain like that.

Based on the docs provided for the [player API](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) t should look something like this.

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/uzixem/1/edit)**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<script>
var f = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
    url = f.src.split('?')[0];

// Listen for messages from the player
if (window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
}
else {
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
}

// Handle messages received from the player
function onMessageReceived(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    switch (data.event) {
        case 'ready':
            onReady();
            break;

        case 'play':
            onPlay();
            break;

        case 'finish':
            onFinish();
            break;
    }
}

// Helper function for sending a message to the player
function post(action, value) {
    var data = { method: action };

    if (value) {
        data.value = value;
    }

    f.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);
}

function onReady() {
    post('addEventListener', 'finish');
    post('addEventListener', 'play');
}


function onFinish() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Vimeo Video', 'finish', url]);
}

function onPlay() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Vimeo Video', 'play', url]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27855315?api=1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above can be simplified a by using the Vimeo Mogaloop api that abstracts the Message Passing API for you, at the cost of loading the Javascript with the library.

**Plugins Ready to use**

Note that the above code will only work as an example and if you have multiple videos on a page it can be harder to get it right. Alternatively you can also use the [GAS](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas) (I'm the main developer there) library that has a [plugin for tracking Vimeo Video](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas#_gastrackvimeo).

**Warning about compatibility**

Note the Warning about compatibility, I guess if you insert the player using the flash method you can get a wider range of browsers supported but kill the player completely for iOS devices:

> With the Universal Embed Code, the only way to interact with the
>   player is by using window.postMessage. postMessage is a relatively new
>   development, so it’s only available in Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox
>   3+, Safari 4+, Chrome, and Opera 9+.

Comment: Seems like an awful lot of workarounds just to take one video "play." Thanks for the help here, very helpful.

Comment: I got this working for my site on stage and dev environments but it doesnt seem to be working on production.  Production site is in https, think this could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Analytics on Steroids](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas#_gastrackvimeo) has a function for tracking Vimeo.  Worth checking into